# cannot applybindings multiple times knockout in MVC partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hi have a parent page in which i have used knockout js to bind model with html element.

Now i make a ajax call to receive a partialviewresult which i place it in a div conbtainer.

All works fine if use the inbuilt mvc model binding.

But when i go for knockout in my partial view as well. I get the errorcannot applybindings multiple times knockout in MVC partial view.

I have even tried using

```
ko.applybindings(new vm(),document.getelementbyId("div1"))
ko.applybindings(new vm1(),document.getelementbyId("div2"))
```

But still get the same error. Is it not possible to get the partial view result from the action method and use knockout in partial view ? I do not want hide the div in my parent page and get a JsonResult and bind it to my div element.

Comment: well from bit of code you given here its should work fine if your are not calling `applybindings` again in some function or somewhere . share us your viewmodel . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following (general layout):

```
<div id="parent">
  content
  <div id="partialTarget"></div>
</div>
```

and you've already applied your bindings to #parent, you have to clean #partialTarget before applying the viewmodel again. #partialTarget has already been bound from the first pass, so to apply the bindings to the loaded contents, you need to do something like this:

```
var reapplyBindings = function(element){
    var vm = ko.dataFor(element);
    if( vm ) {
        ko.cleanNode(element);
        ko.applyBindings(vm, element);
    }
};

element.load(‘path/to/fragment.html’, function() {
    //the [0] selector is needed to be sure we have an actual dom element, not the jQuery wrapper
    reapplyBindings(element[0]); 
    //do whatever you’re already doing
});
```